# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'oRCL_SFDC_TransactionID_t'

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Here is my url I need to call in a get call to resttemplate. How should I use in url?

https://devdatabank.bigmachines.com/rest/v7/commerceDocumentsOraclecpqoTransaction?q={oRCL_SFDC_TransactionID_t:"aDn1h0000008PJLCA2"}&fields=_id,status_t